# shmdt marked for deletion, c, linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

i'm trying to write some code in c dealing with sheared memory in linux,
and I'm not sure when to use the system call `shmdt`, 
and when to use `shmctl (segment_id, IPC_RMID, 0);`

I looked at the man page of shmdt, and read this sentence: 
"shm_nattch is decremented by one. 
If it becomes 0 and the segment is marked for deletion,
the segment is deleted."

what is that marking that the man page mentions? is it `shmctl (segment_id, IPC_RMID, 0);`?
and dose that mean that `shmctl (segment_id, IPC_RMID, 0);` will not detach the segment if there is a process that is still connected?

if someone can explain what dose each call do, I'll be grateful.
Thanks

Comment: Did you consider using POSIX shared memory, see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)

Comment: It is for school assignment, I can't use POSIX.
But thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shmdt()` reverses the `shmat()`-operation.

**shmat:** Maps the shared memory segment in a processes address space

**shmdt:** Unmaps it again

`shmctl (segment_id, IPC_RMID, 0);` marks the segment for deletion, this means, it is the counteroperation to creating the shared memory segment with `shmget(..., IPC_CREAT)`. If the reference counter is 0 when deleting, the segment is deleted immediately. Otherwise, deletion is deferred until the last process unmaps it (either explicitly with `shmdt()` or implicitly by terminating).

Answer (score 0):

to unmap the shared memory mapping from process address space use system call
`shmdt(shared memory start virtual address)` but to delete the shared memory segment use `shmctl()` with `IPC_RMID` or `ipcs` command.
Shared memory segment data structures are maintained inside Linux kernel so deleting shared memory segment means removing or freeing the data structures from kernel.